# GET a URL succeeds in chrome but the get() call never returns

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

I call .get() on the driver instance with this URL
[enter link description here](https://www.eurexchange.com/exchange-en/products/vol/vstoxx/vstoxx-futures-and-options/VSTOXX-Futures-253604)
and I see in the headful chrome instance that the page loads.

However, the .get() call doesn't return after a minute or so. In pdb, I trigger a SIGBREAK and the stack looks like so:

```
-> wdriver.get(url)
 /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py(326)get()
-> self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py(312)execute()
-> response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py(472)execute()
-> return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py(496)_request()
-> resp = self._conn.getresponse()
/usr/lib64/python3.7/http/client.py(1336)getresponse()
-> response.begin()
/usr/lib64/python3.7/http/client.py(306)begin()
-> version, status, reason = self._read_status()
/usr/lib64/python3.7/http/client.py(267)_read_status()
-> line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
/usr/lib64/python3.7/socket.py(589)readinto()
-> return self._sock.recv_into(b)
```

Eventually, after 5mns, it timesout:

(Session info: headless chrome=75.0.3770.142)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=75.0.3770.100 (cd0b15c8b6a4e70c44e27f35c37a4029bad3e3b0-refs/branch-heads/3770@{#1033}),platform=Linux 5.2.11-200.fc30.x86_64 x86_64)

Comment: Why would recv_into be blocking?

Comment: By looking at the HTTP request with F12 chrome, 
It seems there's a never ending refresh request that gets repeated.

Request URL: https://www.eurexchange.com/mstatus/eurex_live.json
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 304 Not Modified
Remote Address: 185.49.16.23:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Is there a way to ignore this part?

Comment: This element statusbox statusbox--green triggers continuous requests to eurex_live.json.
Is there a way to discard that?